# Problem with referring to a class variable in kv language and in python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

Hello I'm having a headache trying to understand why if I try to insert information into my login page and print that into the console it doesn't work. Anyone who can help me?

Here is the code.

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics','width',360)
Config.set('graphics','height',640)
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', False)

from App.constructor import Constructor


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Constructor().constr()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

constructor.py

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class LoginPage(Screen):
    email = ObjectProperty(None)
    password = ObjectProperty(None)

    def btn(self):
        print('Email: ', self.email.text, 'Password: ', self.password.text)


class SignUpPage(Screen):
    email = ObjectProperty(None)
    password = ObjectProperty(None)
    prof = ObjectProperty(None)


class Home(Screen):
    pass
    # def __init__(self):
    #     if prof == True:
    #         self.btn = Button(text='Gestionale per i Clienti',
    #                           on_release='app.root.current = home')
    #         self.blank = Label(text='')
    #         Widget.add_widget(self.btn)
    #         Widget.add_widget(self.blank)


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class Constructor():
    def constr(self):
        return Builder.load_file('constructor.kv')
```

constructor.kv

```
<LoginPage>:
    name: "login"

    BoxLayout:

        email: email
        password: password

        orientation: "vertical"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5}
        size_hint: .7, 1

        Label:
            text: "Email:"

        TextInput:
            id: email
            multiline: False

        Label:
            text: "Password:"

        TextInput:
            id: password
            multiline: False
            # password: True

        Label:
            text: ""

        Button:
            text: "Submit"
            on_release:
                # app.root.current = "home"
                # root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                root.btn()

        Label:
            text: ""

        Button:
            text_align: "center"
            text: "Non hai un account?\nCreane uno qui!"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "signup"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"

        Label:
            text: ""
```

When the function btn() is executed, it prints "Email:  None Password:  None". I followed a tutorial on youtube and I can't understand what is wrong. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `kv` file, you are defining `email` and `password` as attributes of `BoxLayout`:

```
BoxLayout:

    email: email
    password: password
```

try moving those attribute up a level into the `LoginPage`:

```
<LoginPage>:
    name: "login"
    email: email
    password: password

    BoxLayout:

        orientation: "vertical"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5}
        size_hint: .7, 1
```

Comment: Thanks dude you are awesome